# UNIX Command to remove the last character of 2 specific fields in multiple files

Tags: unix, command

May I know how to write a Unix command to remove the last character of 2 specific fields (column 28 and 30) for all rows and in multiple files.

Example of File 1 before removal:

```
0,0,1,14289067,10114404,145,60104212839,1,1,1,8801971507671,1,60104212839,1,8801971507671F,4,170523,170523,1,1,235045,235045,0,0,255,1,0,BMRBGBO,0,BWGKPEI,16758,2,6,00000000000,8801971507671,0,0,,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,3
1,14286085,10114405,142,601124225298,1,1,1,1062895388906858,1,601124225298,1,1062895388906858F,41,170523,170523,1,1,235045,235045,0,1,255,1,0,BINDMAO,0,BWGKPAI,39285,2,6,00000000000,62895388906858,0,,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,2
```

After removal of the last character in fields 28 and 30 in File 1:

```
0,0,1,14289067,10114404,145,60104212839,1,1,1,8801971507671,1,60104212839,1,8801971507671F,4,170523,170523,1,1,235045,235045,0,0,255,1,0,BMRBGB,0,BWGKPE,16758,2,6,00000000000,8801971507671,0,0,,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,3
1,14286085,10114405,142,601124225298,1,1,1,1062895388906858,1,601124225298,1,1062895388906858F,41,170523,170523,1,1,235045,235045,0,1,255,1,0,BINDMA,0,BWGKPA,39285,2,6,00000000000,62895388906858,0,,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,2
```

I want to then proceed to the next file, File 2 and repeat the same process as above. Then this should continue until all files in a directory are completed.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly cut the fields specifying the delimiter as comma. And you do sed command to remove the character that you need using substitutions.

```
cat filename | cut -d',' -f28 |sed s/(.*)./$1/g;
```